# Spheres in different dimension are not homotopy equivalent

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Is there a way to prove that $\textbf{S}^n$ and $\textbf{S}^m$ are not homotopy equivalent if $n\neq m$ without using the machinery of homology or higher homotopy groups?

Comment: So what are we allowed to use? Obviously, the case when one index is $1$ has a simple solution if we know about simple connectivity. Are differential forms allowed? (Granted, that's a disguised version of (co)homology.)

Comment: It's a question from a past exam of a short course in algebraic topology focusing on fundamental group and covering spaces. I suppose there should be an "elementary" way to do this, or maybe the professor just wanted his whole class to fail.

Comment: Well, the spheres (for $n > 1$) are all simply-connected, so there aren't any interesting covering spaces...

Comment: I wonder why anyone bothered to develop machinery which would provide an efficient proof of the seemingly obvious ... ?

Comment: @random: are you sure the professor didn't spend *any* time on homology or higher homotopy groups *that year*? It's possible that whether this happens depends on the year.

Comment: @Qiaochu: maybe he mentioned some things "en passant" but no more than this I think. I will ask him personally what he meant with this question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just for fun, here's an answer that doesn't use the machinery you're talking about, at the expense of using crazier machinery.  Suppose you had a homotopy equivalence $S^n \stackrel{\sim}{\to} S^{n+k}$ for $k > 0$.  By smashing this with $S^{km}$, you get homotopy equivalences $S^{n+km} \stackrel{\sim}{\to} S^{n + (k+1)m}$ for each $k$.  Composing these gives you a sequence
$$ S^n \stackrel{\sim}{\to} S^{n+k} \stackrel{\sim}{\to} S^{n+2k} \stackrel{\sim}{\to} \dotsb $$
and taking the colimit gives you a weak equivalence $S^n \stackrel{\sim}{\to} S^\infty$.  But $S^\infty$ is contractible.  (And as with Andreas's answer, you'd then have to prove that spheres aren't contractible.)

Comment: Just a small note on this excellent answer: The non-contractibility of spheres is *equivalent* to Brouwer's fixed point theorem, and so any argument showing that spheres of different dimension are not homotopy equivalent will, in addition, give a proof of Brouwer's fixed point theorem. As far as I know, all of these proofs take at least a little bit of love as input (smooth approximation, piecewise-linear approximation, homology, or something morally equivalent to any of these.) So I dunno what the OP expects is possible...

Answer (score 9):

I can prove, without mentioning groups, that if spheres $S^m$ and $S^n$ with $m<n$ were homotopy equivalent, then they'd be contractible, but I don't immediately see a group-free proof that spheres aren't contractible.

Suppose $f:S^m\to S^n$ and $g:S^n\to S^m$ were inverses of each other up to homotopy. By cellular or simplicial approximation, you can deform $f$ so that it's not surjective (as $m<n$), and then you can deform it to a constant by pushing away from a point not in the image of $f$.  So $f$ is homotopic to a constant; therefore so are $f\circ g$ and $g\circ f$, which are homotopic to the identity maps of the two spheres.  Therefore, these spheres are contractible,

Comment: Yes, this is the standard way to do this, although the course that I mentioned in the comments to the question didn't cover cellular/simplicial approximation.

Comment: I would think of this as 'using the technology of higher homotopy groups' -- you're essentially using that $\pi_m S^n = 0$, though you're not saying it.  Which isn't a complaint about your answer -- the moral is that we shouldn't be scared of higher homotopy groups, since they were developed precisely to answer questions like this one.

Comment: @random There is a way not involve cellular approximation. You can use the Whitney's theorem that every continuous map between smooth manifold is homotopic to smooth map. Then you can use Sard's theorem.

Comment: I think there is one way not involve homotopy groups(explicitly), you can use Hopf's index theorem.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $S^{n} \simeq S^{n+d}$. Notice that $S^{n}$ is a subspace of $S^{n+d}$. So there exists a deformation retraction $H:S^{n+d} \times I \to S^n$ such that $H((x_1, ..., x_{n+1}, x_{n+2}, ..., x_{n+d+1}),0)=(x_1, ..., x_{n+1}, x_{n+2}, ..., x_{n+d+1})$ and $H((x_1, ..., x_{n+1}, x_{n+2}, ..., x_{n+d+1}),0)=(x_1, ..., x_{n+1}, 0, ..., 0)$.

Restrict $H$ to $n+1$th and $n+2$ coordinate to get $F$. Notice $F$ is still continuous since $H$ is. $F$ defines a deformation retraction from a circle to a an interval. $F((x_{n+1}, x_{n+2}),0)=(x_{n+1}, x_{n+2})$ and $F((x_{n+1}, x_{n+2}),1)=(x_{n+1}, 0)$. But this is a contradiction and hence $S^{n}$ cannot be homotopy equivalent to $S^{n+d}$ as we assumed. $\blacksquare$

Comment: If two spaces are homotopy equivalent and one is embedded in another, this does *not* imply the bigger deformation retracts onto the smaller.  Consider, for example, a Mobius band and its boundary circle.

Comment: Yes, but it is true if the embedding is a trivial cofibration. That, of course, uses the machinery of model categories.